# Use of document.on event inside AngularJS controller to map variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a [datatable](https://datatables.net/) in which I create some labels with x button and when user clicks on it I show modal with a parameter passed through html and then if user confirms modal, I have to call a web services with this parameter in URL.
I'm using bootstrap and AngularJS.
In my datatable code I have:

```
 var user;
 var s="";
 for (user in row.users)
    s += '<span class="tag label label-info"><span>'+row.users[user]+'</span><a>'
    +'<i id="deleteUserFleet" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'+row.users[user]+'" data-target="#deleteUserFleetModal" class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i></a></span>';
 return s;
```

To catch the parameter I'm using

```
app.controller('createFleetController',['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
    //Show username in modal before delete his management fleet
    $(document).on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $scope.username= $(this).data('id');
    });
```

and in my HTML modal code I have

```
<div class="modal" id="deleteUserFleetModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete user from fleet</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="box-body">Are you sure to remove <label>{{username}}</label> management from fleet?</div>
            </div>              
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left"
                    data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-ok"
                    data-ng-click="deleteUserFleet(username)" id="deleteUserFleetButton">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

But I can't see username in my page, if I remove document.on events it works but I need to associate the variable to button click.
How can I make it? Thanks

Comment: Why not use `ngClick`? Angular doesn't know youve changed the scope. Either use `ngClick` or wrap your click handler logic in a `$scope.$apply()`  [related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710478/what-does-scope-apply-do)

Comment: do you mean in my span in datatable?

Comment: I mean the click handler in your controller that you posted. The click handler is delegated to the `i` element with `.remove` class. That's happening outside of the angular framework, most specifically in jQuery, so you need to tell angular its happened using `$scope.$apply`. How do you add that content to the DOM? If using angulars `$compile` service you could just add an `ngClick` to it.

Comment: I didn't use $compile, the content has been added through datatables plugin (ajax request to fill the content into table)