# D3js / AngularJS - drag and data bind the rect's coordinates

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, drag-and-drop, angularjs-ng-model, ng-bind

I want to bind the coordinate x ,y of rect.(Recorded as "Coordinate "). And drag the rect, hoping that the record (coordinate x ,y) will synchronous change.

Below are part of the code.(Complete code [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mamoyunuda/1/edit?html,js,output))

## html

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data">
    <td>({{ item.x }}, {{ item.y }})</td>
    <td>{{ item.width }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.height }}</td>
</tr>
```

## JS

```
$scope.data = [{ 'x': 30, 'y': 50, 'width': 90, 'height': 70 }];

var drag = d3.drag()        
    .on('drag', function (d) {
        d3.select(this)
            .attr('x', d.x = d3.event.x)
            .attr('y', d.y = d3.event.y)
    })
    .on('end', function (d) {
        //update  coordinate x ,y to array
        arrayNum = this.id;   
        $scope.data.splice(arrayNum, 1, { 'x': d.x, 'y': d.y, 'width': d.width, 'height': d.height });
        console.log($scope.data);
    });
```

I also have **$scope.data.splice**  to update the array. And it really update the **$scope.data**.
But it doesn't work on the browser view. How can I modify? Or what can I refer to? Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like angular isn't aware that its scope is being updated by a d3 event.

I added `$scope.$apply()` to your `on end` handler and the display updates in the view as intended after each drag event completes.

```js
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

mainApp.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    'x': 30,
    'y': 50,
    'width': 90,
    'height': 70
  }];

  var drag = d3.drag()
    .on('drag', function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .attr('x', d.x = d3.event.x)
        .attr('y', d.y = d3.event.y)

    })
    .on('end', function(d) {
      arrayNum = this.id;

      // Ensure angular knows about the update to its scope
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        //update  coordinate x ,y to array
        $scope.data.splice(arrayNum, 1, {
          'x': d.x,
          'y': d.y,
          'width': d.width,
          'height': d.height
        });
      });
      console.log($scope.data);
    });

  //create SVG
  var svg = d3.select('.Content')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 300)
    .attr('height', 300)
    .style('border', '1px solid #000');

  var container = svg.append('g');

  container.append('svg:image')
    .attr('xlink:href', 'dog.jpg')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0);

  container.data($scope.data)
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return d.width;
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return d.height;
    })
    .attr('id', function(d, i) {
      return i;
    })
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')
    .call(drag);
});
```

Also, take a read of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18710555/5385381) to better understand why you might need to do this when working with d3.